# Is this possible to write own hotkey for content editable in HTML Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, contenteditable

Actually if we use `Ctrl+B` in content editable it will create a tag

```
<b>Content goes here... </b> like this.
```

Can we add own hot key , For example

> Ctrl+T

```
<a class="tamil">Content goes here...</a>
```

> Ctrl+E

```
<a class="tamil">Content goes here...</a>
```

Please help to resolve this problem, Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything, except writing pseudocode? Also, I'd avoid using existing key-combinations (Ctrl+T opens a new tab).

Comment: Sure, i asked for example. if the  key-combinations  is available i will change the combination. But i need the concept..

Comment: We're not here to make stuff for you. Show us what you've tried and/or researched and we can help you achieve what you want.

Comment: are you heard about shortcut.js  refer this.. http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/

Comment: No, you can't add browser-native behaviour. You can simulate it, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty easy with jQuery:

You can add a keydown-EventListener to every contenteditable element (or just divs, whatever suits your purposes) and in there you can even eliminate standard browser behaviour:

```js
$('[contenteditable=true]').keydown(function(e){
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 70){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#result').append('CTRL + F registered. ');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable=true>
    <p>Some text in here</p>    
</div>

<p id="result"></p>
```

This event listener only get's triggered when the contenteditable element is focused, so if it is not focused, the standard browser functionality for your key combination still get's triggered.

Tested for latest versions of chrome, firefox and ie.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full working code with ctrl+q

```js
$(document).keyup(function(e){
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 81){
   var selection= window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
      var selectedText = selection.extractContents();
      var anc= document.createElement("a");
      anc.setAttribute('id','tamil');
      anc.appendChild(selectedText);
      selection.insertNode(anc);
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Here is a text to work with.
```